# How to set the page title as the default in a drop list box?

Tags: webforms

I have a website that has links to inner pages on its home page.
When the user clicks on any of the link to an inner page, i need the title of the page that is opened to be set as the  value in the field in the webform that is present on the inner page.

Say, for example a inner page has the title "Attractions'. The inner page has a webform that has a field A.

When the "Attractions" page is opened during navigation, how can we make the "Attractions" (page title) value to be set in the webform Field A?